# What's a clean way of using jQuery to turn html into text and count the words?

Tags: jquery

First of all the output:

```
var postContent = wysihtml5Textarea.data("wysihtml5").editor.getValue();
```

Looks something like this:

```
<p>sf sdf asd asd  <b>asd</b> d asd ad&nbsp; asd&nbsp;</p>
```

I want to accomplish the following:

1. Remove all HTML tags
2. Remove all `&nbsp;`
3. Count the words (e.g. and words like "rock-and-roll" should be counted as a single word).

I've been browsing around SO, and I've found the following:

```
 $(txt).text(); remove all HTML tags
 txt.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ''); // remove all &nbsp;
 txt.replace( /[^\w ]/g, "" ).split( /\s+/ ).length; // word count (not sure if it deals with hyphenated words)
 $('#word-count').html(wordCount); // and display it
```

I have no idea how to mix all this in a clean way.

Any suggestions?

Comment: check this link http://jsfiddle.net/Pervez/YJVPZ/257/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/QLgjs/1/

```
 var str="<p>sf sdf asd asd  <b>asd</b> d asd ad&nbsp; asd&nbsp;</p>";

 alert("Plain Text : " + $(str).text());
 alert("Word Count : " +$(str).text().split(" ").length);
```

Comment: $(str).text() will automatically return plain text without html tags and html characters like &nbsp; Please check out the demo Fiddle.

Comment: OK, but strange, the counter increases when I hit space. So space, space, space will count as 3.

Comment: I did `.text()` only and no, it doesn't remove the `&nbsp;`

Comment: alexchenco - are you still facing problem for &nbsp;?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24757/discussion-between-wiz-kid-and-alexchenco)